# Why does this syntax cause it's property constructor to longer point to it's own constructor?

Tags: javascript, constructor

I am learning about prototypes in JavaScript, and came across this behavior, which I guess is just a matter of fact, but wondered if there is any practical reason for it...

Let's say you create an object:

```
function Stormtrooper(){}
```

And then want to quickly fill it with some properties and methods, because after all they're Stormtroopers and they'll be the same :) (And a better reason, you don't want every instance created having it's own individual properties and methods, which would a waste of memory and cause duplication).

```
Stormtrooper.prototype = {
   name : null,
   type: null,
   ID : null,
   rank : null,
   'years of service' : null,
   weapon : null,
   utilityBelt : null,
   giveReport : function(){
     alert('"Click.." This is '+ this.type +' ' + this.ID + ', everything is clear... Nothing to report..."Click"');
    }
};
```

When you `console.dir(Stormtrooper.prototype);` and crack open the `__proto__:` property and look then look into it's `constructor` property, it will point to `Object`, as in the be all end all native Object. Why?

I know you can explicitly add the `constructor` property when you initially create it, but wondered why this is? (That it points to `Object` instead of `Stormtrooper`).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `Stormtrooper.prototype` object *is* just a plain object.

Comment: Yeah. Try `console.log(new Stormtrooper().__proto__)` - otherwise you haven't actually created an instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any object created from an object literal:

```
var obj = { hello: "world" };
```

will be a plain object constructed by the Object constructor. That's exactly what you've got in your code:

```
Stormtrooper.prototype = {
  // ...
};
```